# Firefox extension to auto-load ALL Youtube comments

Tags: firefox, youtube

Is there a Firefox add-on that will automatically load ALL Youtube comments on the page?

There are many addon-ons that will hide the comments, but I am looking for opposite, i.e. load all the comments fully.

There is a separate website, www.youtubextras.com, that can do this if you paste the Youtube link. But I want to see if this extra step can be skipped, load all the comments on the actual Youtube page itself?

Thanks.

Comment: Non Firefox specific solutions: How do I get all comments of a YouTube video?. https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/90791/how-do-i-get-all-comments-of-a-youtube-video